# Threadsafe map-like access to values that only ever exist on one thread

Tags: multithreading, rust, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a struct which needs to be `Send + Sync`:

```rust
struct Core {
    machines_by_id: DashMap<String, StateMachineManager>,
}
```

In my current implementation, `StateMachineManager` looks like this:

```rust
struct StateMachineManager {
    protected: Arc<Mutex<StateMachines>>,
}
```

This works fine as long as `StateMachines` is `Send`. However, it doesn't need to be, and it complicates the implementation where I'd like to use `Rc`.

Performance wise, there's no reason all the `StateMachines` can't live on one thread forever, so in theory there's no reason they need to be `Send` - they could be created on a thread dedicated to them and live there until no longer needed.

I know I can do this with channels, but that would seemingly mean recreating the API of `StateMachines` as messages sent back and forth over that channel. How might I avoid doing that, and tell Rust that all I need to do is serialize access to the thread they all live on?

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=163fd3157cfa50480e58912ff2eb0051) is a minimal example (where I have added the `Send + Sync` bounds to Shepmaster's comment which omitted them)  -- [DashMap](https://docs.rs/dashmap/4.0.2/dashmap/) is a threadsafe map.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: Guessing based on the *code you have provided*, filling in gaps based on the *text you have provided*, [this appears to compile fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d7fdef3c3a21aabf410ab7e40f56aeb6)

Comment: @Shepmaster I can come back and add a minimal example in a bit, but, the important piece is in the first line "I have a struct which needs to be Send + Sync" - the playground example's Core is not.

Comment: Why have a shared map when the values will only be used in their respective threads?

Comment: @kmdreko Because other threads desire interacting with them. It is convenient for the user of `Core` to be able to send updates to the state machines from any thread, and get information about their state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing here was using channels, but I was able to find a way to avoid needing to recreate the API of `StateMachines`.

The technique is to use channels to pass a closure to a dedicated thread the `StateMachines` instances live on which accepts a `&mut StateMachines` argument, and sends the response back down a different channel, which lives on the stack while the access is happening.

Here is a playground implementing the key part
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e07972b928d0f0b7680b1e5a988dae84

The details of instantiating the machines on their dedicated thread are elided.